# Twitter API, C#, ASP.Net

Tags: c#, twitter

how i can retrieve the list of friends and their details (photo, name and surname)

The maximum information about the friends / followers

in Twitter using C#

thanks,

Comment: How are you attempting this at the moment? What appears to be holding you back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use LINQ to Twitter

http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/

Some example code:

```
        var friendshipResults =
            from friend in twitterCtx.Friendship
            where friend.Type == FriendshipType.Show &&
                  friend.SourceScreenName == ownerScreenName &&
                  friend.TargetScreenName == screenName
            select friend;
```

Comment: thanks anima, 
problem: I only shows the first 100
how to solve the problem: show all friends (>100)

Comment: Np, you might find this helpful: http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/discussions/61124

Comment: They have a discussion board, you better ask the devs  :-)